# How does this "for loop" index through the different lines of the object

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning Python 3 the Hard Way lesson #40 on Classes.
I'm trying my best to wrap my head around how this "for loop" counts.

"for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)"

I would also like to know how to convert "line" to a number so I can print out the line number on top of the lyric line.

My slight modification was to put another line "Why you dirty rat" to see if it would print as expected. I also removed commas and the line was appended as expected

````py
class Song():
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
----------------------------------------------------
    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print(line)
----------------------------------------------------
happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued ",
                   "Why you dirty rat",
                   "So ill stay right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around tha family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])
print("\n")
happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()
print("\n")

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
print("\n")```
````

Comment: Try reviewing `Exercise 32: Loops and Lists` first.

Comment: it's "with a pocket"

Answer (score 3):

```
for i, line in enumerate(self.lyrics):
    ...
```

gives you the index and value of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that I can think of for you to do this.

The first method is to get a loop counter for your "for" loop. The second method is iterating the list or tuple using range.

**Method 1:**

```
class Song():
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        i = 0
        for line in self.lyrics:
            i = i + 1  # i here for first line 1 or after print for first line 0
            print(str(i) + " : " + line)
```

**Method 2:**

```
class Song():
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.lyrics)):
            print(str(i + 1) + " : " + self.lyrics[i]) # i + 1 to start at line 1 or just i to start at line 0
```

Comment: don't `+` strings together in python, `print(f'{i} : {line}')` works here, as does `print(i, ':', line)`

Comment: @RyanHaining - print(f'{i} : {line}') does indeed work and print(i, ':', line). However, it all comes down to the matter of taste. I assumed that all of them would convert that i to str somewhere in the code. Nonetheless, thank you for letting me know the methods.

Comment: str() and + is more error prone, and creates extraneous strings. It's typical to see in java or js programmers coming to python, but if you look through any authoritative python resources, you wont find any use of the style you used here, and often explicit advice against it.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Since you know so much about the print and f string. I was wondering if you know which one runs the fastest? why? and which one consumes the most memory?

Comment: It'd take a closer inspection than I have time for at the moment to track memory usage for sure. The + method would most likely consume a little more, though I would be very surprised if it were significant as the intermediate str(i) values would be destroyed as it ran.
The timing isn't a huge deal for printing either, since the usual bottleneck will be the actual printing, not the string construction but [str(i) + line](https://repl.it/@RyanHaining1/PositiveIntelligentAdministrators)  is ~ 1.5x - 2x slower than [f-string](https://repl.it/@RyanHaining1/UniformComfortableDistributeddatabase)

Comment: By "error prone" I mean you can more easily introduce runtime errors. if I accidentally do `i + ' : ' + self.lyrics`, it's easy to forget `str(i)`. The other methods don't have this problem.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Thank you for checking it out. I tested it already. Although, str(i) + string or string + string looked like it creates a new string and that is true. However, Python is a language with a garbage collector So when an object is created and use then nothing else refer to it anymore, what would happen? It will be destroyed. I tested it for 100000 execution under python 3, and str(i) + line use the least memory compare to the other statements.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Now when it comes to speed, you are right, in the 3 statement above, f string is the fastest. But then the second one is str(i) + str. Then the third is actually print(i, str). However, print(i,i,i,i) will operate at the same speed with print(str(i) + " " str(i) + " " + str(i) + " " + str(i)). Nonetheless, print(str + " " + str + " " + str) is twice faster than print(str, str, str). For why it is like that, I don't know. Maybe I should check out the builtin_print() function of python that is in c code.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Nonetheless, thank you for your comment. It got me interested for looking at the print function.

Comment: @RyanHaining - I do understand that it is error-prone but if you test your code you would have seen that int + str will not let the code continue.

Comment: As I said, the actually `print`ing is what is going to take the most time here, so the difference in building the string will be drowned out. I'll take your word about memory usage. `int + str` raises a runtime exception, meaning you won't see the error until you run the code.

Comment: @RyanHaining - That is true, I agree about the runtime exception. I was just wondering if there is there any serious release program that doesn't have to go through the debugging phase? It is an obvious error that is pretty hard to miss and if occur you will also get a simple message with the line number.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Sometimes, there are unusual circumstances where that error can be missed. But that is very rare. That is if someone done a bad design on a try and except block. But as I said, that is rare. So in conclusion, I thank you for your comment. But I would still say, use the syntax you most comfortable with. Unless you intend to achieve speed/security/flexibility/etc... then choose methods that will fit your case. Also, if you working on a project that requires you to follow their guidelines, then you must follow their guideline.

Comment: It's not about missing the error at runtime, it's about minimizing the potential for runtime errors, not all code paths are hit every time the program runs. That final list of concerns is valuable, but other people will use and edit our code. You want to make it (1) easy for them to understand/read quickly and (2) hard to introduce new runtime errors.

Comment: @RyanHaining - I like your comments, but I would still stick to my conclusion. It just that, with this, if it is long code. I know that "i" used to be something that is not a string. Don't get me wrong though, I like f string too. That is just like printf(). or String.format() with auto typing.